# To get the master private key of HD wallet

Tags: private-key, private-key-export, private-key-import

How can I get the master private key of HD wallet bitcoin core satoshi client 0.14.2? Any command for that  on bitcoin core console? Currently I am on Testnet3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to help-> debug window -> console

Enter:

walletpassphrase "your walletpassphrase here" 60, to unlock the wallet if its encrypted.

dumpwallet  "filename", will crate a plain text file in same directory where your wallet .dat file is form which you can get your xprv.

walletlock, to lock your wallet

Don't forger to erase the file after you get the info. Also if u change your wallet password the xpri will change.

Comment: Just one correction. dumpwallet "filepath+filename" and after that It will not automatically create text file but You can go to that file -> properties and then change the extension and open it with notepad. Thanks again